# Wap protocol and Android

Tags: android, webview

When using Android webview I get plain text results instead of webpage for wap pages. I googled and found it is expected behavior. But since it is a third party project I must show wap content somehow with thier custom user agent. What can I do ?.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/). Yes, it would increase the size of the app, but would offer much better performance and still allow the developer to retain control of the application flow.

Comment: Will it support wap protocol. It is a protocol from 90s. I don't think chrome supports it. Are you sure.?

Comment: Chrome doesn't support wap but there are ways to use wap inside WebView. Go with Crosswalk or check [this](http://biswajit-jana.blogspot.in/2011/11/wml-support-in-android.html). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. I will accept this answer if it works